# Cuál sería el mejor diseño para la siguiente relación en una BD?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Primero que todo, estoy empezando a diseñar una app, y aunque he estudiado un poco de BD me surgen algunas dudas, por eso acudo a ustedes, ya sé que es muy simple, pero agradezco la ayuda.

Tengo la tabla

| evaluacion |
| --- |
| id |
| nombre |
| asignatura |
| etc |

y la tabla

| preguntas |
| --- |
| id |
| pregunta |
| Respuesta1 |
| Respuesta2 |
| etc |

Donde una evaluación puede tener múltiples preguntas, y una pregunta puede pertenecer a múltiples evaluaciones.

La opción que se me ocurre es crear una tabla que las relacione:

| relacion |
| --- |
| id_pregunta |
| id_evaluacion |

pero esto significa que por cada pregunta se genera un registro, y no sé si esto sea correcto al momento del diseño de la *BD*.
De nuevo agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: ¿Significa que tienes un _banco de preguntas_? Entonces sí, tu relación M-N se resuelve con una entidad intermedia. Ponle un nombre más diciente que _relación_, eso sí... de _evaluacion_pregunta_ en adelante, cualquier cosa que diga qué es esa entidad

Comment: @Alfabravo, muchas gracias, si, la idea es generar una evaluación y de una crear preguntas y a la vez que esas preguntas vayan a un banco.... lo de "relacion" era por el ejercicio :)

Answer (score 1):

La que das es la definición de una [relación M..N](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/es/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tal y como muestra el gráfico (y como has comentado) se traduce en **una nueva tabla** que contiene las dos claves primarias de las entidades a relacionar.

Eventualmente esa tabla puede tener otros atributos que pertenezcan a la relación (no a las tablas). Por ejemplo en tus tablas (**PREGUNTAS** y **EVALUACIONES**) un atributo de la relación podría ser:

**Puntuación**: Puntuación de una determinada pregunta dentro de la evaluación.

No pertenece a las **PREGUNTAS**, porque en cada evaluación la puntuación de la pregunta es distinta y no tiene sentido que pertenezca a la **EVALUACIÓN**.
Es un dato que tiene sentido *para una determinada pareja* **<evaluación, pregunta>**.

Comment: muchas gracias por la información.